# Issues with loading data through SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am facing some issues in loading a CSV file through SQL Loader.

Here is the control file:

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'mp.csv'
BADFILE mp.bad'
INSERT 
INTO TABLE mp_staging
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
mp_id INTEGER,
mp_name CHAR,
mp_desc CHAR,
oid CHAR,
ptye_cd CHAR,
creation_tmstmp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9",
modified_tmstmp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9",
last_generation_tmstmp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9",
deact_dt DATE,
)
```

Here are some sample records from CSV file:

```
1083,"Test3","","mills_b","PRIVATE",2000-12-06 14:29:21.17,1999-12-06 14:29:21.17,2011-    10-01 04:03:44.6

116,"Mike1","","mills_b","PRIVATE",1999-09-15 11:15:29.42,1999-09-15 11:15:59.663,2011-    10-01 04:01:23.923,,0,"F",""
```

I am facing two issues -

1. The second record gets inserted, but with a different mp_id in the table, as in the value inserted in the table is not 1083, but an alotgether differentnumber, which seems to be generated by a sequence, though I have not referred to any sequence in the control file.
2. The first record fails to load, with this error:

> Record 1: Rejected - Error on table EQ_MP_STAGING, column
>   CREATION_TMSTMP. ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and
>   +9999, and not be 0

Can someone help me in right direction, so that I can debug these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have figured the error. It was all related to the control file definition. All I had to do was remove the data type declarations. 
As far as I figured, when you specify data type, you got to specify the limit of the field. I tried to specify **POSITION(*)**, thinking that this will take care of variable length fields, but I again got the same error.

```
LOAD DATA  
INFILE 'mp.csv' 
BADFILE mp.bad' 
INSERT  INTO TABLE mp_staging
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
( mp_id , 
mp_name , 
mp_desc , 
oid , 
ptye_cd , 
creation_tmstmp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9", 
modified_tmstmp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9",              last_generation_tmstmp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9", 
deact_dt )
```

Answer (score 2):

The separator between seconds and milliseconds is a dot in your CSV file (`1999-12-06 14:29:21.17`) but a comma in your format (`YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9`)

My guess is that it may conflict with the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` directive.

Can you try this ?

```
creation_tmstmp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9",
modified_tmstmp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9",
last_generation_tmstmp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9",
```

Comment: But how come one record gets loaded, but the other fails. Even though, I tried what you suggested, and still get the same error

Comment: BTW, that's not causing the recods to fail. You can specify the format with comma and have the actual data with dot, and it will load without any issue. I jsut tried that!

Answer (score 1):

The changing `mp_id` suggests you have an on-insert trigger on the `mp_staging` table which is always setting the ID from a sequence. If you need the ability to specify ID values, the trigger can check whether the passed `:new.mp_id` is null, and only assign the sequence value if it is. You also need to check that the sequence is set higher than any values you're loading, or you might get clashes later.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought the first time. But, there are no triggers in the system. I just created this temp table for loading data. Also, when I insert a record manually, the ID is preserved: INSERT INTO mp_staging (mp_id) VALUES(123); This inserts a record with MP_ID as 123